# Rewriting URLs from PHP Slim in Nginx Web Server

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, slim

I have a question here. I am developing a PHP SLIM framework application hosted for example on mydomain.com and one of my routes is grouped "api" like this:

```
$app->group(
    '/api',
    function () {
        // All my API routes are here
    }
);
```

I am able to access all my API routes by calling mydomain.com/api/{endpoint}. After deploying my application to production running Nginx, I was asked to convert all my URLs to: api.mydomain.com/{endpoint}. So I created a subdomain and used the code below that I have placed into my nginx configuration file:

```
location ^~ / {
    rewrite ^/(.*$) mydomain.com/api/$1 last;
}
```

It is supposed to map any calls to `api.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/api`. However, it only works when an API call is one level for example, the following will work:

```
api.mydomain.com/resource1
api.mydomain.com/resource2
```

It will fail when using 2 levels, for example the following will fail. I get a "Method Not Allowed" error.

```
api.mydomain.com/resource1/inresource1
```

However when I call `mydomain.com/api/resource1/inresource1` i get a successful request. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I figure it has something to do with my rewrite script and the arguments. I am hoping someone can point me into the right direction.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple (works for me). All I had to do was change my location script to:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass mydomain.com/api;
}
```

That way it forwards all requests (GET and POST) approriately.